# How to make circle profile pic (action button) on AppBar

Tags: dart, flutter

fellow flutter Dev :D
Currently, I'm searching or a way to substitute the Appbar action button icon with a profile pic that I get using an URL. The only problem is that I can't seem to find a way to make it circular. Any idea?

Here is my AppBar Class

```
class MyAppBar extends AppBar {
  MyAppBar({Key key, String  urlFoto})
  : super(
    key: key,
    title: Text(
      "Himatif App",
      style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Strasua'),
    ),
    backgroundColor: Color(0xff3a3637),
    actions: <Widget>[
      // Something here
    ]
  );
}
```

Some code that I've found & tried

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: new Material(
    shape: new CircleBorder(),
  ),
),

/////////////

Material(
  elevation: 4.0,
  shape: CircleBorder(),
  color: Colors.transparent,
  child: Ink.image(
    image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(urlFoto),
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    width: 120.0,
    height: 120.0,
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: null,
    ),
  ),
)

/////////////

CircleAvatar(
  minRadius: 5.0,
  maxRadius: 10.0,
  backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(urlFoto),
),
```

[image: Screenshot]

Something like the upper right icon on the Appbar, but replaced with user profile pic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ClipRRect widget makes its child widget circle. You could wrap that with inkwell to make it functional as button.

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {},
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
    child: CachedNetworkImage(
      width: 120,
      height: 120,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      imageUrl: "imageUrl goes here",
      placeholder: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks man, you saved my life haha :D

one more question thou, it seems to me if the image is not perfectly square, it will break the "circularity". Because of that, I have to reduce the height and width value. Will it not be a circle when the app is installed in another device with different resolution?

Comment: @MuhammadIslamTaufikurahman I have your problem already taken care of. Any portion of the image that overflows from the "square" will be cropped, because I have set the fit property to BoxFit.cover. Try setting a non-square image as your profile picture and see what happens.

Comment: ah, you're right, anyway is there a way to implement placeholder image in this?

Comment: @MuhammadIslamTaufikurahman Yes, you can just give the CachedNetrowkImage a placeholder property and specify the placeholder widget. I will edit my code with some example right now!

Comment: Thanks again mate :D

Answer (score 2):

You can do this also wrap it under a container and make it circular and give the child widget of your Container as your image.
here is the code:

```
appBar: AppBar(
      centerTitle: false,
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff3a3637),
      title: Text("HIMATIF APP"),
      actions: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
          child: Container(
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.white, //remove this when you add image.
            ),
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
              width: 120,
              height: 120,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              imageUrl: "imageUrl goes here",
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
```

here is the result image:
[image]

Comment: This seems like it would solve the problem, but it does not for some reason. Container does not crop its child, so if the child is a square, it will show up as a square image.

Comment: It will use when you add image use something like this: image: new 
                  DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            image: new NetworkImage(
                                "image url")
                        )
                    )

Comment: Basically use the fit property of the image to Boxfilt.fill

Comment: If you do it like that, it will, but the person who posted this question was using CachedNetworkImage, and with that, your solution would not work.

Comment: And if you use CachedNetworkImageProvider with your solution of using DecorationImage, you will lose the benefit of having placeholder widgets and stuff you had with CachedNetworkImage